# How can I convert this recursive solution into an iterative one?

Tags: algorithm, lisp, elisp

I have the following recursive function in Lisp

```
(defun f (item tree)
  (when tree
    (if (equal item (car tree)) tree
      (if (and (listp (car tree))
           (equal item (caar tree)))
      (car tree)
    (if (cdr tree)
        (f item (cdr tree)))))))
```

This function receives a *tree* and an *item* to look for in its immediate leaves.  If *item* is the car of any sublist, then it will return that sublist.  That is,

- `(f 'c '(a b c))       => (c)`
- `(f 'b '(a b c))       => (b c)`
- `(f 'a '((a 1 2) b c)) => (a 1 2)`

I've recently been informed that (Emacs Lisp) doesn't do tail recursion optimization, so I've been advised to turn this into a `while` loop.  All of my training in Lisp has been in avoidance of loops like this.  (I maintain that they are *un*-functional, but that's borderline pedantic.)  I've made the following attempt for more conformative style:

```
(defun f (item tree)
  (let ((p tree))
    (while p
      (cond
       ((equal item (car p)) p)
       ((and (listp (car p))
             (equal item (caar p)))
        (car tree))
       (t (f item (cdr p))))
      (setq p (cdr p)))))
```

<sub>I've shortened the function name for brevity/clarity, but do have a look at [where it is being used](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/blob/6d6fe8e7b7f0bb99b2895fe53c811857ce65e275/stack-core.el#L239) if you are a power-user of emacs.</sub>

Comment: Unless your trees can be nested hundreds of levels, there's no need to avoid recursion. The default recursion limit is 400.

Comment: Your rewritten version is recursing on the `(t (f item (cdr p))))` line.

Comment: @Barmar I know that the `while` 'solution' is currently recursive.  It also doesn't even work, to my knowledge; I haven't tested—it's just something I was working on as an attempt to show so that this wasn't a gimmeh-teh-codez Q. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "iterative" solution is still recursing. It's also not returning the values found in the `cond` expression.

The following version sets a variable to the found result. Then the loop ends if a result has been found, so it can be returned.

```
(defun f (item tree)
  (let ((p tree)
        (result nil))
    (while (and p (null result))
      (cond ((equal item (car p)) (setq result p))
            ((and (listp (car p))
                  (equal item (caar p)))
             (setq result (car tree)))
            (t (setq p (cdr p)))))
    result))
```